# Maven compiler plugin not finding local repositories

Tags: java, maven

I have a local repository as a dependency.

I used `mvn install` to install it in my .m2 folder, and indeed it's there

then in my application pom i have set this dependency

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>us-common</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

I have no errors when importing classes from it in my project but when i try to compile or package the app, with mvn clean compile or mvn clean package Maven gives me the error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project us-auth: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
... package com.company.us.common.security does not exist
```

I have tried to delete the package from my .m2 folder and reinstall it with no luck, i usually use local dependencies in this way, i don't know how to search anymore...

Comment: Have you checked that said dependency indeed contains said package?

Comment: yes i did... I also deleted all the m2/repository folder to make it new, but nothing changes. When i use the local classes in my project I can import them, it's only maven that fails when compiling

Comment: The dependency was not accidentally added to `<dependencyManagement>`? I would call `mvn dependency:list` to see if it really appears and has the correct version.

Comment: `[INFO] The following files have been resolved:
[INFO]    com.company:us-common:jar:0.0.1-RELEASE:compile`

Comment: And you have really unzipped that jar and looked up that the package `com.company.us.common.security` exists in the file structure?

Comment: yes... it' here with its JwtConfig.class file inside BOOT-INF/classes directory

Comment: The class should usually lie in the main directory of the jar. I don't know if/how you can reference classes in `BOOT-INF`.